# grep not matching pattern with space in html files

Tags: linux, grep

My linux server has a folder with all html files. I am trying to find files (names and line numbers) using the below command:

```
grep -rnw '/myfolder/' -e '</tr> <footer class="final-footer">'
```

I know several files that contain this pattern (with a strict single space in between the `</tr>` and `<footer class="final-footer">`). However, the grep command is returning nothing.

When I search just for '`<footer class="final-footer">`' (without `</tr>` and the following single space) the grep returns correctly.

```
 grep -rnw '/myfolder/' -e '<footer class="final-footer">'
```

I tried the above command just to check if my grep syntax is correct. But my specific requirement is to execute the first command. How exactly to do that?

Additional Info

A sample of the pattern in one of the files is this: ....`International, Inc.</td></tr> <footer class="final-footer">`...

Comment: try without the `-w` flag... it will add word boundary condition and perhaps there are word characters before `</tr>`... adding sample input (2-3 lines including the line to be matched) would help in testing..

Comment: Hi, tried removing w flag, but no luck. A sample of the pattern in one of the files is this: ....International, Inc.</td></tr> <footer class="final-footer">...

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the exact string to find, you might as well use the -F option.  No need to fiddle with regular expresions.

```
grep -Fnr '</tr> <footer class="final-footer">'  myFolder
```

From the man page:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions),
          separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
```